# Thread для серверов python

Tags: python

Стаковерфлоу, привет!
Я создаю сайт на python(cgi)

На главной странице у меня лежит сервер:

```
import http.server as BaseHTTPServer
import http.server as CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("192.168.1.3", 80)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

И сайт в папке cgi-bin. Условно:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
print("""
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1 aling = "center">HELLO, STACKOVERFLOW!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
""")
```

Но мне надо сделать так, чтобы сервер обрабатовал несколько запросов ОДНОВРЕМЕННО.
Я понимаю, что надо использовать Threading, но как и куда засунуть - незнаю.

Comment: Вместо `HTTPServer` использовать [ThreadingHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer).

Comment: А как настроить работу с директорией cgi-bin?

Comment: Настройка cgi-bin не меняется.